# Save images from database to sdcard

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sdcard

I want to find a way to save images that are in sqlite database in sdcard,If I use a simple query I can find Image data but How Can I save them for example in `sdcard/temp`
I searched a lot but cant find anything that matches what I want

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're going to be pulling blobs from the db and getting bitmaps or whatever from there. You probably need to see http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html. You can create a file for a given path using the methods in File.

How you encode the bitmap into a blob will affect how you reserialize those bitmaps.

from this post:
[Android: problem retrieving bitmap from database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2266030/android-problem-retrieving-bitmap-from-database)

---

Encoding to the db:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, THUMB_QUALITY, outputStream);
mByteArray = outputStream.toByteArray();  // write this to database as blob
```

---

Reserializing from the db:

```
ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(cursor.getBlob(columnIndex));
Bitmap mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
```

---

Saving to a file:

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
File filename = new File(path, "myImg.png");
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filename);
bitmapp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, <<COMPRESSION_AMT>>, out);
out.flush();
out.close();
```

Comment: thanks for your help but unforchenetly I cant access to android.developer site..:(. We're sorry, but this service is not available in your country. That’s all we know...I just want to pull blobs from db and save them on sdcard as an image.Can you give me some keywords to search abut that?I am new with android and I am learning with examples..Thanks again for your help