# How to save image in storage folder as well as in database when I changed profile picture in android?

Tags: android, database, camera, imageview, directory

My mainactivity has code which takes picture from camera and from gallary .

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private int REQUEST_CAMERA = 0, SELECT_FILE = 1;
    private Button btnSelect;
    private ImageView ivImage;
    private String userChoosenTask;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main11);
        btnSelect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSelectPhoto);
        btnSelect.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                selectImage();
            }
        });
        ivImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivImage);
    }


    private void selectImage() {
        final CharSequence[] items = { "Take Photo", "Choose from Library",
                "Cancel" };

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity11.this);
        builder.setTitle("Add Photo!");
        builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                boolean result=Utility.checkPermission(MainActivity11.this);

                if (items[item].equals("Take Photo")) {
                    userChoosenTask ="Take Photo";
                    if(result)
                        cameraIntent();

                } else if (items[item].equals("Choose from Library")) {
                    userChoosenTask ="Choose from Library";
                    if(result)
                        galleryIntent();

                } else if (items[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }

    private void galleryIntent()
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);//
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"),SELECT_FILE);
    }

    private void cameraIntent()
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE)
                onSelectFromGalleryResult(data);
            else if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA)
                onCaptureImageResult(data);
        }
    }

    private void onCaptureImageResult(Intent data) {
        Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bytes);

        File destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");

        FileOutputStream fo;
        try {
            destination.createNewFile();
            fo = new FileOutputStream(destination);
            fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
            fo.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        ivImage.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private void onSelectFromGalleryResult(Intent data) {

        Bitmap bm=null;
        if (data != null) {
            try {
                bm = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), data.getData());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        ivImage.setImageBitmap(bm);
    }

}
```

It works fine. But, I am not getting how to save this image into the database as well as in a storage folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I resolved all my issue :

```
      private void selectImage() {   
       final CharSequence[] items = { "Choose from Library", "Cancel" };
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle("Add Photo!");
        builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {

                 if (items[item].equals("Choose from Library")) {
                    userChoosenTask ="Choose from Library";

                        galleryIntent();

                } else if (items[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }

    private void galleryIntent()
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);//
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"),SELECT_FILE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
             Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();

                if (null != selectedImageUri) {

                    // Saving to Database...
                    if (saveImageInDB(selectedImageUri)) {
                         //Image Saved in Database...
                        profile_pic.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);
                    }

                    // Reading from Database after 3 seconds just to show the message
                    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            if (loadImageFromDB()) {
                                //Image Loaded from Database...
                            }
                        }
                    }, 3000);
                }
    }
    }
 // Save image in database
    Boolean saveImageInDB(Uri selectedImageUri) {

        try {
            dbHelper.open();
            InputStream iStream = getActivity().getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImageUri);
            byte[] inputData = Utils.getBytes(iStream);
            dbHelper.editUserImage(inputData,LoginDetails.user_id);
            dbHelper.close();
            return true;
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            Log.e("EditProfileFragment", "<saveImageInDB> Error : " + ioe.getLocalizedMessage());
            dbHelper.close();
            return false;
        }

    }
//load image from database
    Boolean loadImageFromDB() {
        try {
            dbHelper.open();
            byte[] bytes = dbHelper.retreiveImageFromDB(LoginDetails.user_id);
            dbHelper.close();
            // Show Image from DB in ImageView
            profile_pic.setImageBitmap(Utils.getImage(bytes)); 
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("EditProfileFragment", "<loadImageFromDB> Error : " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
            dbHelper.close();
            return false;
        }  
    }   
  }
```

and my util.java

```
 public class Utils {

public static byte[] getImageBytes(Bitmap bitmap) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
    return stream.toByteArray();
}

public static Bitmap getImage(byte[] image) {
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.length);
}

public static byte[] getBytes(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    int bufferSize = 1024;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

    int len = 0;
    while ((len = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        byteBuffer.write(buffer, 0, len);
    }
    return byteBuffer.toByteArray();
}

public static void slide_down(Context ctx, View v){

      Animation a = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(ctx,R.anim.slide_down);
      if(a != null){
         a.reset();
         if(v != null){
          v.clearAnimation();
          v.startAnimation(a);
         }
      }
   }
  }
```

dbhelper functions :

```
 public void editUserImage(byte[] imageBytes, String user_id ) {
    try{
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(IMAGE, imageBytes);
    mDb.update(USER_TABLE, cv, ID + " = " + user_id + "", null);
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
 public byte[] retreiveImageFromDB(String user_id) {
    try{
    Cursor cur = mDb.query(true, USER_TABLE, new String[]{IMAGE},
            ID+"=?",new String[]{user_id}, null, null, null,null);
    if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
        byte[] blob = cur.getBlob(cur.getColumnIndex(IMAGE));
        cur.close();
        return blob;
    }
    cur.close();
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

This is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Save Image in storage folder :
            MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), bitmap, "Detected Image", "");

And bitmap in Sqlite database :

```
  public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "mydatbase12";
private static final String TABLE_NAME= name
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
//Pancard variable
private static final String KEY_NAME = "pancard_name";
private static final String KEY_PHOTO = "Photo";


public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

}

// Creating Tables
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_DETAIL_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME+ "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT ,"
          + KEY_PHOTO
            + " blob not null" + ")";




    db.execSQL(CREATE_DETAIL_TABLE);

    System.out.println("table created ");
}

// Upgrading database
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // Drop older table if existed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME

    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);
    db.close();
}

/**
 * All CRUD(Create, Read, Update, Delete) Operations
 */

// Adding new PANCARD detail
public void addData(String data,Bitmap bitmap) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME, data); // tital
    values.put(KEY_PHOTO, Utility.getBytes(bitmap));
    // Inserting Row

    db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);

    db.close(); // Closing database connection
}
```

}

add Utilty class for conver image to byte:

```
  public class Utility {


// convert from bitmap to byte array
public static byte[] getBytes(Bitmap bitmap) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 0, stream);
    return stream.toByteArray();
}

// convert from byte array to bitmap
public static Bitmap getPhoto(byte[] image) {
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.length);
}
```

}

So now pass bitmap in addData method like :  addData("name",bitmap)

Comment: Here Utility.getPhoto(byte[]) returns null. Dont know why ? Can you help me?

Comment: you can get bitmap like :   byte[] blob = cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_PHOTO));
             Bitmap bitmap =  Utility.getPhoto(blob)

Comment: Yee I got that blob which then passed to utility.getphoto() function. still it returns null.

Comment: Please check link for retrieving bitmap : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2266030/android-problem-retrieving-bitmap-from-database

Answer (score 0):

```
   File destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
        System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
```

`// store this imagePath in your database
String imagePath = destination.getAbsolutePath();`

Thanks

Comment: What about images taken from gallary ?

Comment: that will get directly stored on the internal memory of your of your phone